# JavaScript log returns the required string but failed upon submission

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a JS quiz on Udacity.

> a string of a two word name formatted with any mix of capitalization, can you manipulate the string to ensure the first name has a capital first letter and the last name is totally capitalized? Assume there's a space between the names. For instance, turning a string like "cAmEROn PittMAN" into "Cameron PITTMAN". Your answer should be a single string saved to the variable called finalName.

here is my input code:

```
var name = "AlbERt EINstEiN";
function nameChanger(oldName) {
    var finalName = oldName;
    // Your code goes here!
var firstName = name.slice(0,7);
var firstNameA = firstName.charAt(0);
firstNameA = firstNameA.toUpperCase();
firstName = firstName.toLowerCase();
firstName = firstName.substr(1);
var lastName = name.slice(7);
lastName = lastName.toUpperCase();
finalName = firstNameA + firstName + lastName;
 // Don't delete this line!
    return finalName;
}

// Did your code work? The line below will tell you!
console.log(nameChanger(name));
```

The console returns:

> 08 12 2016 09:54:08.533:
>   with unlimited concurrency
>   08 12 2016 09:54:08.764:
>   LOG: 'Albert EINSTEIN'

I know mine is not the most optimized code but since it returns the desired string, it should be right upon submission. However, I only got this:

> --> TEST: nameChanger should return the internationalized name. Returned the correct name:  FAILED
>   expected 'Albert EINSTEIN' to equal 'Geoff NORMAN'

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: This is obviously linked to some kind of test that we have no possibility of using. Since this is course, perhaps you should go through the proper channels and ask the course instructor instead?

Comment: Because you are using the hard coded `name` variable inside the function , when you are more than likely supposed to use the passed argument `oldName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this explanation in code by comments:

1. split first name and last name
2. get the first letter of first name capitalize and add remaining of first name by lower case
3. add the second name by capitalize

```js
function nameChanger(oldName) {
//your code starts here in your case you need to return out variable
var d = oldName.split(" ") // this will return you array of two strings 
var out = d[0][0].toUpperCase() //take the first string first letter capitalize
out += d[0].substr(1).toLowerCase() + " " //add the remaining firstname by lowercase substr will give you sub string from 1 index 
out+= d[1].toUpperCase(); //add the second name by upper case

return out;
}

console.log(nameChanger("AlbeRt Eienstien"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve the output.

```
var name = "cAmEROn PittMAN";
var names = name.split(" ");
var finalname = names[0].toString().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + names[0].toString().substring(1,names[0].length).toLowerCase() + " " + names[1].toString().toUpperCase();
console.log(finalname);
```

Here the finalname returns "Cameron PITTMAN"
Use split instead of slice and it will return both words in an array and you can manipulate the data as you need.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use an argument as another commenter already mentioned.**
I DIDN'T CHANGE YOUR CODE VERY MUCH, BTW.

*NOTE:* you want to ask questions that help *more* people than simply for an answer to a quiz. :-)

Have a good day - hope you love learning to code.

---

**See if this helps.**

```js
function nameChanger(oldName) {
    var finalName = oldName;
    // Your code goes here!
    var firstName = oldName.split(' ')[0];
    var firstNameA = firstName.charAt(0);
    firstNameA = firstNameA.toUpperCase();
    firstName = firstName.toLowerCase();
    firstName = firstName.substr(1);
    var lastName = oldName.split(' ')[1];
    lastName = lastName.toUpperCase();
    finalName = firstNameA + firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  
    // Don't delete this line!
    return finalName;
}

// Did your code work? The line below will tell you!
console.log(nameChanger('geOff NoRmAn'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would help in the future:

```
var name = "AlbERt EINstEiN";

function nameChanger(oldName) {
   var finalName = oldName;
// Your code goes here!
   var names = oldName.split(" "); //Split the string in an array of 2 elements, using the space (" ") as separator.
   names[0] = names[0].slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + names[0].slice(1).toLowerCase(); //Converts first letter into UpperCase + rest of firstname to LowerCase.
   names[1] = names[1].toUpperCase(); //Converts lastname to UpperCase.

   finalName = names.join(" "); //Joins both names into a string separated by a space.

// Don't delete this line!
   return finalName;
};

// Did your code work? The line below will tell you!
console.log(nameChanger(name));
```